# Interaction in playframework

Tags: javascript, http, playframework

I'm new to Playframework, and get a question:
  When people search something, the result is rendered in some chart generated by google visualization. When people selected some point on the chart, I got the row# and col#. I need to get these two data to backend, fetch some data using this row# and col# and render the data in a new chart.
Any idea on how to route this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use jquery.ajax() and jsRoutes to call your backend.
then, you should add a new function in the "complete" tag option of ajax method (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) that will render your new chart.